# Kotlin async callback unit test

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I have a class:

```
class SomeClass(private val executor: Executor) {
        fun doSomething(id: Int, callback: (String, Int) -> Unit) {
            executor.execute {
                val intValue = id + 1
                val stringValue = "Some string result"
                callback(stringValue, intValue)
            }
        }
    }
```

How I can create a unit test for the doSomething method?

Comment: Please invest some time into researching your case and come back with a specific question, instead of asking for a complete implementation

Comment: This kind of use case is really calling for [coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html), to be honest, and it would make testing this trivial. If you want to stick with the executor version, then maybe you can provide a special executor for your test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched this question for about 3 days. I was hoping this could be resolved using Mockito. Fortunately today I found [ConcurrentUnit](https://github.com/jhalterman/concurrentunit) utils for testing async code.

My solution:

```
val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
lateinit var someClass = SomeClass(executor)

@Test
fun test() {
    val waiter = Waiter()
    someClass.doSomething(1) { string, int ->
        waiter.assertNotNull(string)
        waiter.assertEquals(int, 2)
        waiter.resume()
    }
    waiter.await(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
}
```

Thanks all for your help!